# How object oriented programming is better for efficiency of memory and execution time?

Tags: function, oop, memory

I want to know that how object oriented programming is better for efficiency of memory and execution time? Which factors involved in making this paradigm more reliable for these two things. Why simple function oriented programming is not good than OOP in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like one of those random question CS professors ask in the programming languages course when they run out of ideas for focused questions. In any event -- why would you think that OOP is better for efficiency or memory? Objects invariably involve overhead. Reliability and code reuse are different matters. Functional programming is neither better nor worse than OOP. Both are useful abstractions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object Oriented Programming (OOP) was not invented for memory efficiency or execution performance, so do not expect those.

OOP is the programming methodology aimed to minimize bugs and code deficiencies (spaghetti code, code duplication, etc.) in the large projects. OOP improves code readability/maintainability/extensibility.

If you use OOP language, it does not mean you use OOP. OOP is the way you write code, not the coding language.